# Combining two laravel eloquent queries

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two queries.  One that returns all cases where `interview` equals 1 and the other where `interview` equals 2.  I then add both of the up. Currently in my db I have two cases where interview is 2 and one case where interview is 1.  Both of my statements work.  However, when I try to combine them for some reason I get 4.  Not really sure why.  How do I combine them to get the correct number.

Here are the two statements that add up to 3

```
Scan::where('user_id', $client->id)->where('interview', '2')->count();
Scan::where('user_id', $client->id)->where('interview', '1')->count();
```

When I tried to combine then using and orwhere statement it returns 4

```
Scan::where('user_id', $client->id)->where('interview', '2')->orwhere('interview', '1')->count();
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is `AND` and `OR`:

The first one strictly returns result using `user_id` AND `interview` **while** the second one looks like `user_id`, AND `interview = 1` OR `interview = 2`

This mean based on the look is that, you'll have more result since the query matches more record with `interview = 2` *without user_id*

But, You can use `whereIn` function for this, that is:

```
Scan::where('user_id', $client->id)
   ->whereIn('interview', ['2', '1'])
   ->count();
```

It returns results where you have the `interview` value as either 2 or 1.